# GPS location not pickup in some divces

Tags: java, android, gps

I have some situations , there is galaxy note , galaxy s3 , lenovo 7 inch

I'm using GPS location provider , but in galaxy note can't pick up any points inside my home .

in galaxy s3 it works in home and in out street .

in lenovo 7 inch it not works at home and streets

how can i fix this ?

```
public class StoPoints extends ListActivity implements LocationListener
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, this);

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location2) {
    location = location2; 
}
```

Comment: I will just offer this in case it helps -- I had a GPS unit that sometimes did not produce readings that were at all accurate until it had moved around some.  If I just plugged it in while I was at home, it didn't appear to work.  But if I plugged it in (giving it power) and moved out of the house onto the street, and then back into the house and upstairs, then it would give an accurate reading.  I have no idea whether this will help, but you were talking about "working at home".

Comment: It makes no sense that a single piece of code doesn't work on different devices. Make sure you turn on the GPS on lenovo phone. Also try to get last known location from the LocationManager. Try the following :  location = locationManager
.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Comment: You get a phone with a better GPS radio.  Cheap GPS units won't be able to read the signal inside of buildings.

Comment: i want to ask about using INTERNET to get gps location how far it accuracy meters ?